get data that triggered cloud function into cloud function (google.cloud.bigquery.v2.JobService.InsertJob)
i have a cloud function which gets triggered when data is inserted into a specific BigQuery table (event type - google.cloud.bigquery.v2.JobService.InsertJob). My requirement is to get this "row data" into the cloud function logic.
cloud event(input to function) has details about event type. This has details like project id, dataset id, table etc. But it doesn't have the actual data that was inserted. Not sure if insert id or something from this log can be used to get the actual data that was inserted.
sample cloud event data:
{'attributes': {'specversion': '1.0', 'id': 'projects/GCP_project_id/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fdata_access-p8u2s9e59ouj1718902358732636', 'source': '//cloudaudit.googleapis.com/projects/GCP_project_id/logs/data_access', 'type': 'google.cloud.audit.log.v1.written', 'datacontenttype': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'dataschema': 'https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloudevents/jsonschema/google/events/cloud/audit/v1/LogEntryData.json', 'subject': 'bigquery.googleapis.com/projects/GCP_project_id/datasets/BQ_Dataset_name/tables/BQ_Table_name', 'time': '2024-06-20T16:52:39.469382553Z', 'recordedtime': '2024-06-20T16:52:38.732636Z', 'methodname': 'google.cloud.bigquery.v2.JobService.InsertJob', 'resourcename': 'projects/GCP_project_id/datasets/BQ_Dataset_name/tables/BQ_Table_name', 'servicename': 'bigquery.googleapis.com'}, 'data': {'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.events.cloud.audit.v1.LogEntryData', 'protoPayload': {'status': {}, 'authenticationInfo': {'principalEmail': 'userid@abc.com'}, 'requestMetadata': {'callerIp': '29.285.100.0', 'callerSuppliedUserAgent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/126.0.0.0 Safari/537.36,gzip(gfe),gzip(gfe)', 'requestAttributes': {}, 'destinationAttributes': {}}, 'serviceName': 'bigquery.googleapis.com', 'methodName': 'google.cloud.bigquery.v2.JobService.InsertJob', 'authorizationInfo': [{'resource': 'projects/GCP_project_id/datasets/BQ_Dataset_name/tables/BQ_Table_name', 'permission': 'bigquery.tables.getData', 'granted': True, 'resourceAttributes': {}}], 'resourceName': 'projects/GCP_project_id/datasets/BQ_Dataset_name/tables/BQ_Table_name', 'serviceData': {}, 'metadata': {'tableDataRead': {'jobName': 'projects/GCP_project_id/jobs/bquxjob_24008bd9_19066907743', 'reason': 'JOB'}, '@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.BigQueryAuditMetadata'}}, 'insertId': '-p0u2j8e59auj', 'resource': {'type': 'bigquery_dataset', 'labels': {'dataset_id': 'BQ_Dataset_name', 'project_id': 'GCP_project_id'}}, 'timestamp': '2024-06-20T16:52:38.732636Z', 'severity': 'INFO', 'logName': 'projects/GCP_project_id/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fdata_access', 'receiveTimestamp': '2024-06-20T16:52:39.469382553Z'}}
Need help with solution or any alternative to this. Thanks in advance.

You can't. For now, there is no CDC in BigQuery. Something announced at Cloud Next named "continuous query" will be able to sink the change in PubSub and you will be able to handle the inserted data. For now, you only have a log event that tell you a job (a query) has been ran on BigQuery

Building on the above ... one possible solution is to use the APPEND_TVF (ref: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/change-history#appends-tvf).  Using this, you can query what rows have been appended/inserted into a table for a given time range.  I could imagine your cloud function being triggered because "some" rows were inserted and then using this SQL function to get the values of the rows inserted.
